# Explain why the following are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

$p_{1} = \sin(t)$, $p_{2}=\cos(t)$, $p_{3}=0$, $p_{4}=t^{7}$.

Are they linearly dependent because there are 4 elements in 3 dimensions?

Comment: I guess because $p_3=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is trivially linearly dependent to any vector $v$ since $v=\lambda\cdot 0$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field on which your vector space is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In any vector space $V$, for any subset $X \subset V$, if $\mathbf{0}\in X$ then $X$ is linearly dependent: $1\cdot\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$, but $1 \neq 0$.